Having trouble in consuming messages from kafka
I have launched my broker and zookeeper inside a docker . I started producing messages locally in my pycharm using my localhost:9092 . I could see my broker printing messages inside the docker . When I Try to consume those messages in Databricks there is this long ‘Stream initialising...’ message and it stops suddenly . Please help me out to resolve this issue
Producer
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
from data import get_users
import time

def json_serializer(data):
    return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")
def get_partition(key , all , available):
    return 0
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=json_serializer,
                         partitioner = get_partition)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        registered_user = get_users()
        print(registered_user)
        producer.send("kafka_topstream", registered_user)
        time.sleep(40)

Docker compose :
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - myfirststream

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - myfirststream
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

networks:
  myfirststream:

DATABRICKS
I try to consume message using this DataFrame (should I have to use - ‘172.18..0.3:9092’ ?)
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "kafka_topstream") \
  .load()

I tried changing the IP addresses , My kafka producing messages inside the docker but im trying to consume it outside (databricks) please advice me to overcome this issue

Databricks runs in the cloud, right? Why would localhost work?

@OneCricketeer exactly instead of giving localhost can I try giving the IP - 172.18..0.3:9092 or should I have to go with some reachable IP ? please do advice me

I don't know your public IP. You'll need to port forward your router to reach your local Kafka instance... It'd be easier to setup Kafka in the Cloud and allow Databricks to connect with that. Otherwise, install Spark locally also
